# How to run our softwares in server for 20 users

Tags: windows-server-2012

We are going to buy a server and we need it to be able to run some of our accounting softwares in server and make session for each user connecting remotely to open their own desktop and allow them to run the accounting software clients all at the same time and do their work.
im  wondering what technology and softwares can we use in windows server 2012 and what we need to establish something like this?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want each user to have their own desktop and you're using windows server then you need to set up Remote Desktop Services ([Terminal Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services))

Here's a quick [installation guide](http://www.wackytechtips.com/installing-and-configuring-remote-desktop-services-rds-on-windows-server-2012/).

One particularly important consideration is that you'll need to ensure that the accounting software can run on terminal server and supports multiple users in this manner as some are file based and don't run well when multiple users are accessing the same data file at one time.

Make sure you add plenty of RAM and plenty of CPU Cores to the server you buy otherwise your users may complain about speed.  Use SSD's for the OS as a minimum in a RAID array.